# Как использовать 2 версии python в Visual Code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

Понадобилась установка двух версий Python, но столкнулся с проблемкой. Visual Studio Code работает только с первой версией(python 3.8.1), а запустить проги с помощью версии python 3.7.4 не получается. Как правильно произвести настройки, чтобы работать с обеими версиями?

Comment: Не советую использовать VS Code для программирования на Python. Для этого есть PyCharm.

Comment: Внизу слева на панели статуса написан текущий интерпретатор, можно нажать на него и переключиться на другой.

Comment: @Struckture, есть ли там возможность использовать 2 версии python пареллельно друг другу?

Comment: @DGDays, в PyCharm можно настроить нужный интерпретатор для проекта. Но если быстро нужно что-то потестировать не очень удобно использовать PyCharm - он довольно неповоротливый, особенно когда индексирует глобально установленные модули, приходится для проекта еще создавать виртуальное окружение. Для одномодульных проектов проще использовать VsCode.

Comment: @insolor, спасибо огромное за совет. Может знаете как использовать в VsCode две версии python параллельно?

Comment: @DGDays, уже написал - второй комментарий под вопросом)

Comment: @insolor, упс, не заметил Спасибо большое

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. В vscode нужно установить расширение Python ([ms-python.python](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python))
2. При открытом python файле справа на панели статуса нажмите на версию интерпретатора и переключитесь нужную.

В списке выбора должны отобразиться доступные интерпретаторы, в том числе интерпретатор виртуального окружения, если проект открыт как папка в vscode (меню Файл - Открыть папку) и виртуальное окружение есть этой папке.

Также есть возможность вручную прописать путь к интерпретатору, если он по какой-то причине не нашелся.

[image: Скриншот]

Данная возможность **не работает**, если установлено расширение "Code runner" - выбранный интерпретатор при запуске python файла будет игнорироваться.